# Cosine relation with polynomial

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

Can anybody tell me how can we write cosine fucntion iterms of a polynomial? May be there exist some relations that can approximate a cosine function with an equivalent polynomial of some degree of x.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for the [Taylor series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series) of a function which relates a function to an infinte polynomial.

The Taylor series of $\cos(x)$ at $a=0$ ;

$\cos(x) = 1-\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^4}{4!} -\frac{x^6}{6!}+\frac{x^8}{8!}-\cdots$

This is found by calculating the derivatives of $\cos(x)$ at $x=0$ and applying the formula of the taylor series gives as an expansion of;

$f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty f^n(a)\frac{(x-a)^n}{n!}$

where $f^n$ is the $n^{th}$ derivative of $f$

Answer (score 0):

Could you possibly mean the [Taylor Series](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TaylorSeries.html) of cosine? Which comes out to be: $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^n\frac{x^{2n}}{2n!}$

Expanded, it looks like: $1-\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^4}{4!}-\frac{x^6}{6!}+\frac{x^8}{8!}-...$

Answer (score 0):

You can approximate the cosine by means of a polynomial in a certain range in the least-squares sense by minimizing

$$E=\int_a^b\left(\sum_n p_nx^n-\cos x\right)^2 dx.$$

To achieve the minimum, you cancel the gradient, by

$$\frac{\partial E}{\partial p_m}=\int_a^bx^m\left(\sum_n p_nx^n-\cos x\right)dx=0$$

or, after expansion,

$$\sum_np_n{\frac{(b^{n+m+1}-a^{n+m+1})}{n+m+1}}=\int_a^bx^m\cos x\,dx.$$

After evaluation of the RHS integrals, you get a linear system of equations to be solved for the $p_n$.

---

You can also obtain approximations in the minmax sense (largest pointwise absolute error as small as possible) by means of the Chebychev theory and the [Remez algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remez_algorithm), but this is more involved.

---

Note that it is advantageous to exploit the periodicity and symmetries of the trigonometric functions and approximate sine and cosine over $[0,\pi/4]$.